# Cucumber Scenarios to be run in Sequential Order

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have few concerns regarding cucumber framework:-
1. I have single Feature file(steps are dependent on each other)and i want to run all the scenarios in order, by default they are running in random order.
2. How to run a single feature file multiple times?

I put some tags and tried to run but no luck.

```
@Given("Get abc Token")
    public void get_abc_Token(io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable dataTable) throws URISyntaxException {
        DataTable data=dataTable.transpose();
        String tkn= given()
                .formParam("parm1",data.column(0).get(1))
                .formParam("parm2", data.column(1).get(1))
                .formParam("parm3", data.column(2).get(1))      
        .when()
        .post(new URI(testurl)+"/abcapi")
        .asString();

        jp=new JsonPath(tkn);

        Token=jp.getString("access_token");

        if (Token==null) {
            Assert.assertTrue(false,"Token is NULL");           
        }else {


        }       

       }


@Given("Get above token")
    public void get_abovetoken(io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable dataTable) throws URISyntaxException {

    System.out.println("Token is " +Token);



    }
}
```

So in the above steps i am getting token from one step and trying to print token in other step but i got null and not the actual value, because my steps are nunning randommmally
Please note i am running TestRunner via testng.xml file.

Comment: If you mean that you have several feature files and you want them to be run in a certain order, you need to name them such that the filenames will sort alphabetically.  i.e. testcase-001, testcase-002, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Cucumber and testing tools in general are designed to run each test/scenario as a completely independent thing. Linking scenarios together is a terrible anti-pattern don't do it.

Instead learn to write scenarios properly. Scenarios and feature files should have no programming in them at all. Programming needs to be pushed down into the step definitions.

Any scenario, no matter how complicated can be written in 3 steps if you really want to. Your `Given` can set up any amount of state. Your `When` deals with what you are doing, and your `Then` can check up any number of conditions.

You do this by pushing all the detail down out of the scenario and into the step definitions. You improve this further by having the step definitions call helper methods that do all the work.